# Can OpenCSV ignore trailing commas on records?

Tags: csv, opencsv

A CSV with trailing commas like this:

```
name, phone
joe, 123-456-7890,
bob, 333-555-6666,
```

processed like this:

```
CSVReaderHeaderAware r = new CSVReaderHeaderAware(reader);
Map<String, String> values = r.readMap();
```

will throw this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Error on record number 2: The number of data elements is not the same as the number of header elements
```

For now I'm stripping commas from input files using sed:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/,*\r*$//' {} \;
```

Is there some easy way to tell OpenCSV to ignore trailing commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCSV maintainers commented [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/feature-requests/127/).  As of OpenCSV v5.1 there is no simple way to accomplish this and pre-processing the file using sed, etc is best for now.

Answer (score 0):

According to link provided in @Andrew's answer it's a malformed CSV input.

But as own maintainer suggests ( [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/feature-requests/127/) ):

> If you know you will always have single-line records, you could
> derive a class from CSVReader, override getNextLine() to call
> super.getNextLine(), then cut off the trailing comma, and of course,
> pass your new reader into opencsv to use in parsing.

In other words, create your own CustomCSVReader and remove the last comma.

Here's an example:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class CustomCSVReader extends CSVReader {

public CustomCSVReader(Reader reader) {
    super(reader);
}

@Override
protected String getNextLine() throws IOException {
    String line = super.getNextLine();
    if (line == null) {
        return null;
    }
    
    boolean endsWithComma = line.endsWith(",");
    if (endsWithComma) {
        return line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
    }
    return line;
}
}
```

The Model Converter using CustomCSVReader

```
public class CustomCSVParser{

public List<User> convert(String data) {
    return new CsvToBeanBuilder<Transaction>(new CustomCSVReader(new StringReader(data)))
            .withType(User.class)
            .build()
            .parse();

}
```

The Model class

```
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;

public class User {

@CsvBindByName(column = "name")
private String userName;

@CsvBindByName(column = "phone")
private String phoneNumber;

// Constructor, Getters and Setters ommited
}
```

Test Class

```
class CustomCSVParserTest {

private CustomCSVParser instance;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    instance = new CustomCSVParser();
}

@Test
void csvInput_withCommaInLastLine_mustBeParsed() {

    String data = "name, phone
     joe, 123-456-7890,
     bob, 333-555-6666,";


    List<User> result = instance.convert(data);

    List<User> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(
            new User("joe", "123-456-7890"),
            new User("bob", "333-555-6666"));

    Assertions.assertArrayEquals(expectedResult.toArray(), result.toArray());

}
}
```

That's it.